# InvalidPayloadException in apache camel when using interface based proxy

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using interface as apache camle as proxy
Interface declaration,

```
public void publish(@Body Abc abc, @Header("header1") String header1);
```

It is throwing exception as,

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available
>   of type Abc

Comment: The error tells you the message body is not of the expected type, Abc so it cannot process the message. Check your message body to see what type/object you actually have

Comment: if i do exchange.getIn.getBody() it gives me the Object of BeanInvocation with args property as array containing 2 object one of type Abc and second String.

Comment: All i am trying to do is to trigger a camel route through proxy object and pass the values from proxy to header and body,

Comment: what version of Camel do you use?